# jQuery keyboard event fires on wrong input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm creating simple forms without direct submitting, than running script before. So classic hitting enter will not send the form. However, since users are often hitting enter button to send a form, I create simple extension for hitting enter that is calling script when button is clicked.

For example, I have a simple form:

```
<form id="testForm">
  <input type="email" id="email" />
  <input type="password" id="pass" />
  <button id="btnLogin" type="button">Login</button>
</form>
```

And extension I created is looking like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.noEnter=function(options){
        let settings=$.extend({btn:""},options);
        function _init(){
            $(this).on("keypress",function(event){
                if(event.keyCode === 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#"+settings.btn).click();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        this.each(function(){_init();});
        return{}
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Then in script I call something like this:

```
$("#email").noEnter({btn:"btnLogin"});
$("#pass").noEnter({btn:"btnLogin"});
$("#btnLogin").click(function(){
.....
});
```

And this is working. **Problem is that it is working twice**, for each input field. Looks like other input field is accepting keypress (or keydown) event. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `this` is referring window object in `_init` function to avoid that try below code

```
(function($){
    $.fn.noEnter=function(options){
        let settings=$.extend({btn:""},options);
        var self = this;
        function _init(){
            $(self).on("keypress",function(event){
                if(event.keyCode === 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#"+settings.btn).click();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        this.each(function(){_init();});
        return{}
    };
}(jQuery));

$("#email").noEnter({btn:"btnLogin"});
$("#pass").noEnter({btn:"btnLogin"});
$("#btnLogin").click(function(e){
    console.log('righty');
});
```

There is working example is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3o3ojm0/) if you want to try

Answer (score 0):

use event.stopPropagation();  to prevent executing further.

```
$(this).on("keypress",function(event){
                if(event.keyCode === 13) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#"+settings.btn).click();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```